# In what column is an item dropped?

Tags: puzzle-craft

If you match enough items, it will create a new item (for example, match 8 carrots and you'll get a tomato). In what column will that tomato drop?

I often end up with tomatoes scattered around my playing field, unable to match because they are adjacent. I want to upgrade my chances of combining higher level items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say authoritatively, but from experience I suspect they're dropped randomly into the board to replace the tiles you removed when you made the long match.  You could potentially make them more likely to drop in a particular column by limiting yourself to a low number of columns in a given match, but that's hard to do when you're trying to make a long enough match to get them in the first place.

As you level up, the higher level crops will get easier and easier to create, making them more prevalent and more likely to be adjacent.  If you need a couple in the meantime, you can create tools to clear these crops from the board without having to make a match.